# UIView animation terminates prematurely

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I'm trying to use the `+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` method to animate a `UITableViewCell`'s background colour from white to red. However, the colour will not animate, it immediately jumps to red. I've switched out `setBackgroundColor:` for `setOpacity:` and that works fine. What could be causing the animation to fail using background colour? Below is the code I'm using:

```
UITableView * tableView = (UITableView *)[self view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
  [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] 
      setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate changes to color properties. You will have to create two background views and fade between them using their `.alpha` properties.

Comment: That's not true, according to [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816): 'Changes to this property can be animated'.

Comment: Hmm. OK, try setting the color on cell.backgroundView instead. Perhaps the cell has disabled implicit animations on itself.

Comment: That works even less. Instead of jumping to the correct colour, it doesn't change it at all. Good idea though! And incidentally, the reason I'm not just using alpha to do it is that I'm using grouped table cells, which are a pain to add custom full-cell subviews to.

Comment: I did a small experiment on a new project with non-grouped cells. I was able to animate the colour to change, but only the parts of the background that were not behind the label rectangle. Setting no label text allowed the whole cell to animate.